# A group operation on $G^S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question is:

> Assume $S$ is a nonempty set and $G$ is a group. Let $G^S$ denote the set of
>   all mappings from $S \to G$. Find and operation on $G^S$ that will yield a
>   group.

Can the operation on $G^S$ be the exact same as the operation that is defined for the group $G$? Why or why not?

Comment: It cannot be *exactly* the same operation since the sets are different, but it is pretty close.

Comment: It is unnatural to exclude the special case $S=\emptyset$, which works perfectly well. When people are irritated by this, they haven't really understood what is going on in the general case. And when they become responsible for creating exercises, they pass their confusion to the students who don't know it better ... anyway ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation of $G^S$ can't be the same as the operation on $G$, because the elements of $G^S$ are functions, and the operation on $G$ applies not to functions but to elements of $G$.

Perhaps an example will help.  Let's say that $G$ is the set $\{E,O\}$, with the following operation $\oplus$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\oplus & E & O \\
\hline
E&E&O \\
O&O&E
\end{array}$$

Let's also say that $S$ is the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Then $G^S$ is the set of all functions that take some number between 1 and 5 and which give you back, for each number, either $E$ or $O$.

For example, one element of $G^S$ is a function I'll call $OOOOO$, which has $OOOOO(x) = O$ for each $x$ in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Another element of $G^S$ is a function I will call $OEOEO$ which has $OEOEO(x)$ equal to $O$ when $x$ is an odd number and to $E$ when $x$ is an even number.

In all, there are 32 different elements of $G^S$, each one a different function from $S$ to $G$.

Your job is to think of an operation, $\star$ that will make these  32 elements into a group. So for example you should be able to say what $OOOOO\star OEOEO$ is; it should be one of the 32 functions.

The $\star$ operation can't be $\oplus$, because that applies to $O$ and $E$, not to these 32 functions.  But there is a simple way to define $\star$ that is based on $\oplus$ in a natural way.

Comment: thank you, this helped me a lot just thinking about it. I really appreciate the time you took to write this out.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Lilluda: You can upvote helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Think about $G^S$ as a product of $S$ copies of $G$, how would you define the operation on the product? Now find a way to translate it back to the functions.

Comment: From all the hints I gave (here, and generally), I think this one was the hardest to come up with... everything I had was essentially a solution. I'm quite happy with this!

Comment: Sorry, but this kind of confused me even more. Is there a different way to think about this?

Comment: @Lilluda: I don't want to reveal the solution to you. Start with $S=\{1,2\}$. My hint suggests an analogy between $G^S$ and the product of $2$ copies of $G$. How do you define a group structure on $G\times G$? Now think about this product is actually the same thing as $G^S$, and from there the general case should be obvious.